# How to pass opentracing data using json

Tags: go, microservices, opentracing, distributed-tracing

My API-gateway starts a tracer and a span for validate email. Then its passed to `user-service` for validation.

I want to pass this `span` details to `user-service` as a json object and start another `span` as a

`tracer.start_span('Validate Email', child_of=API_gateway_span)`

To do it, I have used following struct:

```
type checkEmail struct {
    GatewayTracerSpan opentracing.SpanContext `json: gatewayTracerSpan`
    Email             string                  `json: email`
    Uuid              string                  `json: uuid`
}
```

In `function()`

```
validateEmailSpan := apitracer.tracer.StartSpan("Validate Email")

emailJson := checkEmail{
            GatewayTracerSpan: validateEmailSpan.Context(),
            Email:             email,
            Uuid:              uuid,
        }
```

But always `GatewayTracerSpan` is empty value.
I have just started distributed-tracing. Here I selected to use json over native `http-headers` as its easy for upgrade any protocol change.

Is this possible? If so, am I doing it right? Or what mistakes did I make?

Comment: What do you need from `validateEmailSpan.Context()`? Do you just want to see your spans, that are created in different services, linked together or do you need some specific information from `validateEmailSpan.Context()`?

Comment: @eminlala I just want to pass span data to my next service and start a new span as keeping API-gateway span as parent.

Answer (score 3):

One way to link spans from different services is to use `uber-trace-id` from the parent span. If you have `LogSpans` set to `true` in your `ReporterConfig`, `uber-trace-id` is what gets printed out (`"Reporting span xxx-xxx-xxx"`).

Here is how it might look like in the code:

```
//API Gateway
carrier := opentracing.TextMapCarrier{} //you can use any type of carrier or even create your own
ctx, _ := opentracing.GlobalTracer().Extract(opentracing.TextMap, carrier)
span := apitracer.tracer.StartSpan(name, ext.RPCServerOption(ctx))
_ := span.Tracer().Inject(span.Context(), opentracing.TextMap, carrier)
uberTraceID := carrier["uber-trace-id"]
```

You can now pass `uberTraceID` instead of `validateEmailSpan.Context()` to your other services.

You can use this function in your other services:

```
//Email service
func NewChildSpanThatFollows(name, uberTraceID string) opentracing.Span {
    carrier := opentracing.TextMapCarrier{}
    carrier.Set("uber-trace-id", uberTraceID)
    ctx, _ := opentracing.GlobalTracer().Extract(opentracing.TextMap, carrier)
    span := opentracing.StartSpan(name, opentracing.FollowsFrom(ctx))
    _ := span.Tracer().Inject(span.Context(), opentracing.TextMap, carrier)

    return span
}
```

This works for me if I need to see spans between services linked together in a parent-child manner. If other information needs to be passed as well, I would suggest passing it as regular data in the JSON object, then either create my own `Carrier` or use tags if needed to do a search with that passed data.

```
span.SetTag("request_id", requestID)
```

EDIT:

[Here](https://github.com/yurishkuro/opentracing-tutorial/tree/master/go) you can find a great tutorial on using opentracing. It uses `HTTPHeadersCarrier`, it has a step by step walkthrough, but it's basically the same process as above.

Comment: I changed my code as you have suggested, but still TraceID is null.

Comment: @Sachith I've added a useful link in the answer above. Beside this, I can't really help more without taking a look at the code you've implemented.