# SpanContext not found in Extract carrier in microservice

Tags: go, microservices, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I am trying to implement a Go-based microservice system. I have two service and I try to `Inject` and `Extract` span data.

In my first service, I have:

```
func (apitracer apiTracer) validatemail(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    validateEmailSpan := apitracer.tracer.StartSpan("Validate Email")

    apitracer.tracer.Inject(
            validateEmailSpan.Context(),
            opentracing.HTTPHeaders,
            opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(req.Header))
        req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
```

In service two :

```
wireContext, err := opentracing.GlobalTracer().Extract(
        opentracing.HTTPHeaders,
        opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(req.Header))
```

I get following error :

> SpanContext not found in Extract carrier

If I dump `log.Println("Form values : ", req.Header.Get("Uber-Trace-Id"))`, I get proper `Uber-Trace-Id` value which is same as Service-One.

Request headers are set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696512/post-data-faild-using-http-newrequest)

Edit : After @eminlala

Tracer init step.

```
type apiTracer struct {
    tracer opentracing.Tracer
}

// Tracing function
func startTracing(service string) opentracing.Tracer {

    cfg := config.Configuration{
        Sampler: &config.SamplerConfig{
            Type:  "const",
            Param: 1,
        },
        Reporter: &config.ReporterConfig{
            LogSpans:            true,
            BufferFlushInterval: 1 * time.Second,
        },
    }
    tracer, _, _ := cfg.New(
        service,
        config.Logger(jaeger.StdLogger),
    )
    opentracing.SetGlobalTracer(tracer)

    return tracer
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go/ext`? If not, try adding `ext.HTTPMethod.Set(span, r.Method)` and `ext.HTTPUrl.Set(span, r.URL.String())`  before injecting.

Comment: @eminlala added, but still the same result. **SpanContext not found in Extract carrier**

Comment: could you please add your tracer init code, I need to see which propagator is used?

Comment: @eminlala Added tracer init parts to the question.

Comment: @Sachith are you still having this problem, and if so are you able to provide the direct link to the source code?

Comment: @bsapaka Yes, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I see that you missed to add `Injector` and `Extractor` options when creating the tracer. It should look something like this:

```
zipkinPropagator := zipkin.NewZipkinB3HTTPHeaderPropagator()

tracer, _, err := cfg.New(
        e.ServiceName, config.Logger(jaeger.StdLogger), config.ZipkinSharedRPCSpan(true),
        config.Injector(opentracing.HTTPHeaders, zipkinPropagator),
        config.Extractor(opentracing.HTTPHeaders, zipkinPropagator))

opentracing.SetGlobalTracer(tracer)
```

`ZipkinPropagator` is from `github.com/uber/jaeger-client-go/zipkin` package.

You should try `ZipkinPropagator` because it has less configuration than the plain `HTTPHeaderPropagator`. `ZipkinPropagator` receives less parameters, but it's also less flexible. Also, the error you received is from the `Extract` method is of type `opentracing.ErrSpanContextNotFound`. `Extract` method for `ZipkinPropagator` is less complex as it only check for the `TraceID` before sending the `opentracing.ErrSpanContextNotFound` error (when `carrier.TraceID()==0`).

You can use the `HTTPHeaderPropagator` as well, but it has a bit more complex setup, and `Extract` method checks for more things other than `TraceID` before sending the `opentracing.ErrSpanContextNotFound` error (checks for `debugID` and `baggage` that is extracted from `HeadersConfig`).

EDIT:

Looking back at your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740621/how-to-pass-opentracing-data-using-json) regarding `opentracing`, if you haven't included `Injector` and `Extractor` setup, that might have been the problem why `uber-trace-id` was not found when extracting the span context in the target service.